# How to add a button in Django admin form?

Tags: django

I want to add a button which has same functionality as SAVE button in DJango and I want to modifying it's response_change function .

How do I do that ?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. However, if you want to make a button that saves data to your django database, you can do so by adding a JavaScript event listener on that button, and making the listener send a XMLHttpRequest to your server, then saving data inside a view function.

Comment: Hi ,I wanted to add a additional button in django admin form .https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/2006/ -- this link helped me a lot .

Answer (score 0):

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2005/ 
---This link helped to add a button in django .